# Using formula(paste(…)) in a loop: "Using formula(x) is deprecated when x is a character vector of length > 1"

Tags: r, regression

My codes:

```
for (x in dataset$year){
  controls_c <- paste(controls, collapse = "+")
  spec <- formula(paste(dataset$Inflation,
                        "~MonetaryPolicyShockRomer&Romer+",
                        controls_c))
  regs_controls[[x]] <- lm(spec, data = dataset %>% filter(x))
}
```

And I am having the following error:

Using formula(x) is deprecated when x is a character vector of length > 1.
Consider formula(paste(x, collapse = " ")) instead.

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: Add `collapse = " "` to the `paste()` call, like the error suggests.

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and, in particular, ensure that the code in the question is complete including all inputs shown using `dput` so that anyone else can copy the code and paste it into their session to reproduce the problem.

Comment: It seems odd to be pasting the _value_ of `dataset$Inflation` into the LHS of the formula, and the _names_ of the controls on the RHS after your fixed `~Moneta...` portion. Further, `dataset %>% filter(x)` seems odd when `x` is a year. I suspect you really need your `for` loop to be `x in unique(dataset$year)` and your `lm` call to use `filter(dataset, year == x)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speculation:

```r
controls_c <- c("somefield", "anotherfield", ...)
regs_controls <- list()
controls_c <- paste(controls, collapse = "+")
for (x in unique(dataset$year)) {
  spec <- formula(paste("Inflation", "~",
                        paste(c("`MonetaryPolicyShockRomer&Romer`", controls_c),
                              collapse = " + ")))
  regs_controls[[as.character(x)]] <- lm(spec, data = dataset %>% filter(year == x))
}
```

Changes from your code:

- I've combined your single column `"MonetaryPolicyShockRomer&Romer"` into a vector along with `controls_c` so that we can collapse them together into the single RHS of the formula;
- wrapped that `"Monetary..."` in backticks, since the `&` is not otherwise a "legal" character within an object name (i.e., a column name). It is possible to use, you just need to wrap in backticks to be able to use it, in the same fashion that you *can* have column names entirely of (or starting with) numbers
- changed the loop so that you're looping only once per unique `year` found
- changed the storage of `year` in the list as a string instead of a number; doing `regs_controls[[2021]] <- ...`, for instance, will try to store the results from `lm(..)` in the 2021st position in the list, which is not necessarily what you are going for (I'm inferring). Instead, `regs_controls[["2021"]]` will be used, which will go into the first available position (depending on how much iterations in the `for` loop before this year).

Comment: Many thanks for this amazing answer. I have a few more questions since get the code  from my friend. What is the purpose of using ```regs_cotnrols <- list()```.  I know what ```paste()``` does but I do no understand why we use it in the model. FInal question is why do we use the name of the variables with quotes? Many thanks.

Comment: Could you explain the inside of the loop

Comment: The `regs_controls` list holds the return value from each call to `lm(.)`, this just pre-instantiates it; I inferred by the lack of definition in your code that that's what you were doing. The `paste` is used to combine the names of columns you want to add to the model. Frankly, neither `controls_c` nor `spec` need to be in the loop, the only thing needed would be `lm(..)`, in which case this whole thing can be reduced to something like `out <- lapply(split(dataset, dataset$year), function(z) lm(spec, data=z))`

Comment: but why would I want to combine the names of columns ? Model should only include the variables no?

Comment: Frankly, I'm not sure I know anymore. Your question is lacking many details that might help understand this better. What is `dataset$Inflation`? If `controls` is not changed in the loop, why do you recalculate `controls_c <- paste(controls, collapse = "+")` every time? What _is_ `controls`? What _actually happens_ with your data when you look at the return from `dataset %>% filter(x)`, the data used for your regression? What do you intend to have as results after this loop is complete? I tried to guess, but it appears that I may have missed the mark.